# Implementing staggered grid view with multiple selection in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have been browsing through net to get example to implement the below UI using gridview or staggered grid view in flutter, but didn't find any good examples.

Any related example would help !!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be archived using [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget. Also, you can use packages.

```
 List<int> selectedIndex = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Wrap(
      children: [
        ...List.generate(
          33,
          (index) => GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                selectedIndex.add(index);
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.amber),
                color:
                    selectedIndex.contains(index) ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text("Item $index"),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin works like that [multi_select_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter)